# List item after removing line-height from CSS is not united

Tags: html, css, line-height

I am using storeship theme for wordpress, but there is one thing I dont like, so I wanted to change. When category name is longer than 25 chars, line is divided to 2 lines. I was looking for problem and I found out that the reason is in css line-height param, but when I remove it, it looks like the menu is broken(not united). How to fix it to way like original but with no big space between 2 lines?

[image: with line-height]

Without line-height

[image: Without line-height]

```
<section
class="main-banner-section-wrapper  no-separator banner-img-position-background banner-layout-default banner-layout-type-boxed-layout banner-title-background-none data-bgg banner-layout-type-none"
data-background="">

<div class="boxed-layout">
    <div class="banner-slider-5 clearfix row-sm">
        <div class="col-4 float-l pad">
            <div class="aft-top-categories-vertical-lists toggle-categories category-dropdown-active">
                <button type="button" id="aft-top-categories-btn">
                    <h3 class="af-top-cat-head">
                        Categories</h3>
                </button>
                <div class="category-dropdown catgory-list list-only top-3-products">
                    <ul class="aft-category-list-set">
                        <li class="aft-category-list aft-mega-menu-list">
                            <a href="" title="">
                                <h4>Name1</h4>
                                <span class="category-badge-wrapper"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="aft-category-list aft-mega-menu-list">
                            <a href="" title="">
                                <h4>Name2</h4>
                                <span class="category-badge-wrapper"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="aft-category-list aft-mega-menu-list">
                            <a href="" title="">
                                <h4>Long Name1, Long Name21111</h4>
                                <span class="category-badge-wrapper"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="aft-category-list aft-mega-menu-list">
                            <a href="" title="">
                                <h4>Name4</h4>
                                <span class="category-badge-wrapper"></span>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul> 
                    <span class="aft-view-all-products">
                        <a href="" title="">
                            <i class="fa fa-th" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                            All categories</a>
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[CSS](https://pastebin.com/fsnaajBQ)

Comment: Use padding instead of line-height

Answer (score 0):

Fixed problem with removing line-height and add padding to element

thanks @Super User